# How to stop thrift TNonblockingServer in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, rpc, thrift

I start a TNonblockingServer from one thread:

```
void *start_server(void *) {
    server->serve();
    return NULL;
}

pthread_create(&daemon_thread, NULL, start_server, NULL);
```

, and call `server->stop()` from the main thread, then try to use `pthread_join` to wait the background thread exiting gracefully. However the main thread hangs at the `pthread_join` call.

How could I shut down the thrift server gracefully?

Comment: It is kind of expected that the main thread "hangs" while waiting for the other thread to terminate. Is it doing that properly, as a response the stop command?

Comment: What I expected is that when I call server->stop() from main thread, the server->serve() in background thread would finished, so that this thread can exit. Therefore it would be safe to use pthread_join in main thread to wait this background thread "start_server()" to exit..however "pthread_join()" hangs *forever*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response

You would just need to stop the underlying libevent

For example, a slightly delayed stop:

```
tv.tv_usec = 500000;
tv.tv_sec  = 0;
event_base_loopexit(myTNonBlockSvr->getEventBase(), &tv);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT `TNonblockingServer::stop()` [is not implemented](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/thrift/trunk/lib/cpp/src/server/TNonblockingServer.h?revision=1028168&view=markup). The `TNonblockingServer` destructor does attempt a clean shutdown though, so you *might* be able to delete server and have the server shutdown.

This is a complete hack though, and ideally `stop()` would be properly implemented.